# Can not kill the AWS CodeDeploy instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I just run my app within `CodeDeploy` and now can not stop the `EC2` instances.
I removed everything inside `CodeDeploy` but nothing has changed and the instances are unstoppable.

What can I do with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy agent/ deploment shouldn't block the process to stop an EC2 instance. Are you able to see any useful log in systemlog or kernal log?